# Prove that $\{(x,y)\mid x\in\mathbb Q\}\cup\{(x,y)\mid y\in\mathbb Q\}$ is a connected subset of $\mathbb R ^2.$

Tags: calculus, general-topology, connectedness

In my notebook, something is very briefly, not in detail whatsoever, path connectedness mentioned, and two assumptions are made about $x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb Q.$ If anyone can prove this I would greatly appreciate it... I tried myself, but got nowhere.

Comment: Consider vertical and horizontal line segments which stay in the set to prove path connectedness.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this, it says this is the answer in my notebook aswell, I do not understand it

Comment: WHy cant you connect tthe two points directly ?

Comment: Because you might pass through points where neither coordinate is rational. Consider $(\pi,0)$ and $(0,\pi)$. If you drew a straight line between them, then you'd hit the point $(\pi/2,\pi/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in B$. Define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow B$ as follows: if $x_1\in\Bbb Q$, set $f$ on $[0,1/4]$ to form a line segment from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(x_1,0)$, and on $[1/4,1/2]$ to form a line segment from $(x_1,0)$ to $(0,0)$. Otherwise $y_1\in\Bbb Q$, and we can set $f$ on $[0,1/2]$ similar to above, except going from $(x_1,y_1)$ to $(0,y_1)$ to $(0,0)$.

On $[1/2,1]$ define $f$ similarly as on $[0,1/2]$ but in reverse and to $(x_2,y_2)$.

I'll leave it to you to check that $f(x)\in B$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and that $f$ is continuous. Them it follows that $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ are connected by a path, so $B$ is path-connected, and thus connected.